# How to optimized scrollview?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, memory-management, data-structures

I'm implementing a scroll list with some data just like any social media feed for mobile devices. There are some text and an image. It is working fine. The program brings 10 users data at a time from the database and displays on the screen. But the problem is after display 40/50 users data app is going to slow gradually to load more data because of all data store in RAM. After loading around 100 users data app is crashed.

I'm using Unity C# and trying to improve my app performance like any social media feed. I want to implement something like Android ArrayAdapter. But I'm not sure about it will solve the problem or not. So How I manage memory or how can I achieve this?

Comment: have you made sure the problem originates from ram using the profiler? if so how large are your user images?

Comment: Yes. I have seen in profiler. The images are larger than 2mb. In 1gb ram iPhone, app is crashed after loaded 30/35 users data.